# kernel is different when listed by uname versus pacman

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

If I run `uname -r` on my system it returns 6.1.19-1-lts, but if I give the command `pacman -Q linux`, then it returns "linux 6.2.5.arch1-1".

So what exactly does this mean? My kernel is different than what? I guess I don't understand what pacman is telling me. I mean if I am running lts, then how can pacman say I am running something different?

Comment: Is `linux 6.2.5.arch1-1` the only thing `pacman -Q linux` returns? AFAIK, to apply new kernels, you need to reboot the system after a kernel update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the lts kernel (linux-lts) and the stable kernel (linux).

If `uname -r` returns  6.1.19-1-lts then that is the kernel currently in use.

`pacman -Q linux` is asking “what version of the stable kernel have I got installed?

So in summary, you are running the lts kernel but have the stable kernel also installed.